# What is the standard way to connect with database using c++?

Tags: c++, mysql

I am trying to understand how a connection can be made with any database using c++ code, i searched many places and came across connector c++ MySQL, although it seems good but there is no explanation on how the connection is being made (I am looking for an explanation which starts like : first of all you need to create this object which will be used to store connection string and then you do this ...).

**EDIT :** I am new to programming and want to know how the database connectivity is achieved , I searched and got results like ODBC and cpp connector , there is documentation available for these but it seems like they wrote it for experienced programmers and it is not beginner friendly. so in conclusion I wanted to know what are the ways available to connect with any database, if you could give some links which can help a beginner to create a connection with a database or any book related to database connectivity.

Comment: See MySQL Connector C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Database access has never been standardised in C++. Thus,

> What is the standard way to connect with database using c++?

**None.** There are only non-standard ways.

Maybe some day in the future C++ will have a standard database access layer. There has been a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3886.pdf) to add one to the language, which was apparently discussed in a [2014 C++ committee meeting](http://meetingcpp.com/index.php/br/items/c-papers-for-issaquah-concepts-database-evolution.html), but don't expect anything anytime soon.

---

Generally, you should be aware that database software is not limited to client/server architectures like MySQL. For simple client-side databases, SQLite is a common alternative. In any case, database systems usually provide a C API, which can be used directly from C++ code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , it made me realise that not all people on stack overflow are mean.

Comment: @Balraj Getting downvotes is by no means _mean_, read the tooltip when hovering the mouse pointer over the questions downvote button.

Answer (score 1):

Tr with ODBC:
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/

Is more documented and more simple